# R: Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters

Tags: r

I tried a variety of ways to input the parameters. Please help..

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(optimx)

data<- matrix(c(0.05,0.09,0.62,
            0.45,0.12,0.15,
            0.17,0.92,0.3,
            0.15,0.3,0.5,
            0.21,0.14,0.6,
            0.36,0.36,0.7),ncol=6)
colnames(data) <- c("D1","D2","D3","E1","E2","E3")
param = matrix(c(1,2,3))
diffq = matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3)
S =  matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3)

funct = function(param,data){
  for(i in 1:3) {
    for(j in 1:3) {  
      diffq[i,j] <- (param[1]*data[i,"D1"]-param[1]*data[j,"E1"]+
                   param[2]*data[i,"D2"]-param[2]*data[j,"E2"]+
                   param[3]*data[i,"D3"]-param[3]*data[j,"E3"])
      S[i,j] = ifelse(diffq[i,j] < 0, c(0.3), 
                  (ifelse(diffq[i,j] == 0, c(0.8), c(1.3))))
    }
  }
  AUC = sum(S)/nrow(S)/ncol(S)
  return(-AUC)
}    
optimx(c(param),funct,method="Nelder-Mead")
```

> Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess,
>   lower,  :  Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters

Comment: note that your ifelse doesn't seem right

Comment: You do not supply a value for the `data` function input in `funct`.

Comment: indeed, try `optimx(as.vector(param), funct, data=data)`

Comment: Thank You @baptiste ! It works..